# How to display the time length of video (current time/ total time)?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.7

I would like to ask how to display the displayed time of the video which show only in system using AS 3.0. Example: it show the seek time and total time using trace(). It there any information or solution to solve it? 
I appreciate it any of you able to answer it. ^^
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you are using a `NetStream` object to stream your video?

If so, the `NetStream` class has a variable called `time` which gives you the seek time in seconds.

```
var ns:NetStream;
// load video, etc
...
// update every frame
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);
function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void {
    trace("seek time: " + ns.time);
}
```

As for the total time, you can get that from the video's metadata by listening to the `onMetaData` event. See [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flashmediaserver/3.0/hpdocs/help.html?content=00000180.html).